# how can I run dapr subscriber quickstart in prod environment

Tags: dapr

All quickstart examples using .Net SDK show 'dotnet run' as the way to run ASP.Net Core applications. See https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/quickstarts/pubsub-quickstart/#tabs-1-net

`dapr run --app-id order-processor --components-path ../../../components --app-port 7001 -- dotnet run`

I figured dotnet publish and then replace "dotnet run" with calling the exe or "dotnet order-processor.dll" would work as well, but it does not. The application starts and can be accessed directly but not through dapr.
What would be to way to run the subscriber quickstart in a prod environment (not using dotnet run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm, my mistake. dotnet /order-processor.dll works but you have to adapt the port to the default. After changing 7001 to 5000 it works as expected. This does the trick:

```
 dapr run --app-id order-processor --components-path ../../../components --app-port 5000  -- dotnet .\bin\Debug\net6.0\publish\order-processor.dll
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).